# How to get the value of a directive's attribute from properties file based on Locale?

Tags: java, jsp, properties, locale, taglib

The task is to conditionally include a css file based on the Locale. To do this, I am going to put the path to the Locale dependent css file in the properties file. I am using the following directive to include the css in a page -

```
<%@ include file="/path/to/my.css" %>
```

How do I get the value of file attribute from properties file?

**Note**: I Have fmt taglib implemented and working fine. So, I would like to do something like -

```
<%@ include file="<fmt:message key='page.css'/>" %>
```

But the above does not work for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@include` is compiletime (get executed when JSP is to be compiled) while `<fmt:message>` is runtime (get executed when JSP is to be executed). You want to use the runtime include `<jsp:include>` instead.